# How to rename file with bash .sh script

Tags: android, bash, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following code in a .sh file for pipeline to get the apk file path.
However, I want to rename the file fist.

i.e. rename abc.apk to QA_abc.apk

LATEST_DEBUG_APK=$(ls -lrt ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk | tail -1 | awk -F" " '{ print $9 }') #Pick the latest build apk.

LATEST_RELEASE_APK=$(ls -lrt ./app/build/outputs/apk/release/*.apk | tail -1 | awk -F" " '{ print $9 }') #Pick the latest build apk.

LATEST_QA_APK=$(ls -lrt ./app/build/outputs/apk/QA/*.apk | tail -1 | awk -F" " '{ print $9 }') #Pick the latest build apk.

Comment: The question is not quite clear, so the file name that you are getting from the variable `LATEST_QA_APK` is let's say `abc.apk` and you want to rename it to `QA_abc.apk` in the same directory. Am I right? Please explain your question in detail with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `mv` for that.

```
mv /path/to/abc.apk /path/to/QA_abc.apk
```